# R Kable splitting the column names up oddly

Tags: kable

I am getting bizarre formatting using `kable.`

```
  make.tab = function(res,true){
  avg.res = round(apply(res,2,mean),2)
  tab = rbind(avg.res,true)
  #rownames(tab)  = c('Samples','Truth')
  t(tab)
}
```

Then I source this function into an Rmarkdown notebook.

```
source('hepler.R')
mt = make.tab(res, true)
kable(mt)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Somehow using a different `kable` package gets rid of this.

```
#library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
```